# JQuery returning select dropdown list returning value instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Concatenating the selected options of three dropdown lists using JQuery to then use as a lookup value in a JSON file.

It is concatenating, but it looks like it's returning the values rather than the text of the selected option?

I know that `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();` is an option, however the lists are produced by reading a JSON and then placing the outcome in an `<Option value= >` - will this still work?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e67y9wjf/1/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"will this still work?"* What happened when you tried `$("#id option:selected").text();`?  Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#bcr').val()` will get the value or ID of the dropdown.

You can use `$('#bcr option:selected').text()` to get the value inside the dropdown ie the text

Comment: Brill thank you @JamesS, I was on the right lines with what I wrote just doubt in whether it would work with what I wrote :)